# Where did the link to meta go?

Tags: support, meta, hyperlinks

I just came here to ask a question, but I can not figure out how to find the way to meta without manually entering the URL in my browser. Where do I have to click?

Usually, I clicked on the Stack Exchange logo and it opened a menu where I was able to select the sites to visit. Where is that now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link to meta is now located in the right-most dropdown menu, the one that has the stackexchange icon:

[image]

Comment: After all these years ... lol, thanks!

Comment: They just changed the layout quite a bit.